# RSS "collector" or proxy (client and server in one) tool

Tags: linux, rss

I'm searching for some Linux tool which can run as a service, retrieves one or more RSS feeds and provides them like a webserver to be retrieved from a RSS reader.

The idea is to let this tool run constantly on a Raspberry Pi to retrieve items from an RSS feed with high article frequency (press releases) but only with the last 10 or so items available.

The collected items could then be retrieved by my main computer one or two times a day (which would be too few for direct retrieval).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any software that do exactly this, but you can use Planet or any other news aggregator, like Rawdog or wordpresss with plugins, and configure the aggregator to serve a larger amount of items in rss.

There is a privacy problem, in this solution.

The other, more common and privacy aware, solution is to self host a feed reader, like [OwnCloud News](https://github.com/owncloudarchive/news) or [TinyTiny RSS](https://tt-rss.org/).